# jQuery if condition for exactly matching classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code presented below in php echo statement. Brackets are empty but can assure you that statement which I put inside to modify CSS works - with one flaw.

I want it to work for elements with class attribute equal to "zoom" or "zoom first". Unfortunately it works for all elements which have "zoom" class, including "woocommerce-main-image zoom".

I could exclude elements with "woocommerce-main-image" class, but I would prefer a cleaner solution, applying my code to elements with these 2 specified class attributes:

```
if ($(this).hasClass("zoom") || $(this).hasClass("zoom first")) {}
```

Comment: $(this).attr("class") === "zoom" || $(this).attr("class") === "zoom first"

Comment: cleaner solution check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZdNaf/

Comment: so it'll only check if the class is exactly equal to either "zoom" or "zoom first"

Comment: There is no such thing as class `"zoom first"`, that means it has both classes `"zoom"` and `"first"`. As such you might want to change your class to be something like `zoom-first`. Classes are seperated by spaces, so if an element has `class="foo bar zoom"` it still has the `zoom` class.

Comment: I realize that they are multiple classes, but contained in one class attribute. Unfortunately it is the way woocommerce and zooming plugin in Wordpress name the elements, so changing class names is in this case a difficult and invasive task.

Comment: Thanks everyone for support, I will accept Jorrex' solution as an answer. I got it to work as it should. The solution from jsfiddle is very good, but I am using interaction with clicked element's siblings what complicates the use of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search elements that has the "zoom" class exclusively, or elements that has both "zoom" and "first" exclusively, maybe you could try the below:

```js
var search = ["zoom", "zoom first"];

$.each(search, function(i, v) {
  var classes = v.split(' ');

  $('.' + classes.join('.'))
    .filter(function() {
      return $(this).attr('class').split(' ').length == classes.length;
    })
    // Do something here
    .css('background', 'yellow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="zoom">zoom</div>
<div class="zoom foo">zoom foo</div>
<div class="first zoom">first zoom</div>
<div class="zoom first">zoom first</div>
<div class="zoom foo first">zoom foo first</div>
<div class="zoom first foo">zoom first foo</div>
```